# loop through array of array using each function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to iterate through check_programs which contains program_enrollments to see if they include "btest"
.Both of them are arrays.
How do i write it using each do??

```
if check_programs[1].program_enrollments[0].username.include?("btest") 
  current_enrollment.status == "accepted"
elsif
  current_enrollment.status == "pending"
end
```

Comment: can you give more insights on what exactly the check program contains, and what you need , is that check_program is, are you want to iterate through each program_enrollments?

Comment: This is a textbook [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). `#each` should only be used when you only care about the side effects of the loop such as printing to a buffer or modifying the items in the loop. For EVERYTHING else [Ruby has better methods](https://blog.appsignal.com/2018/05/29/ruby-magic-enumerable-and-enumerator.html) such as `map`, `select`, `reject`, `inject` etc.

Comment: Also you're confusing assignment and comparison. To call the setter you want `=` not `==` .  `elsif` needs to be used with a condition `elsif foo == 'bar'` which must be on the same line.